# What happens when I complete A Helping Hand?

Tags: cities-in-motion

In the Berlin scenario one of the objectives offered is called 'A Helping Hand'. If I remember correctly it is offered by a gentleman that runs a bus/tram maker.

The requirement for the objective is to purchase 3 new buses or trams, and no reward is listed on the objective screen, but after completing it the man says he 'will fix something up for me.'

What is he fixing up? Is he just saying that, meaning the objective was just to get me to buy his vehicles, or has something else changed?

Answer (score 1):

> **Objective 16 - A Helping Hand**
>
> January will present another task, to buy 3 new buses or trams.
>   Another simple task, buy them and the task completes.
>
> This is the final task. You can now popup the above finish button from
>   the previous objective and continue to the next scenario.
>
> Job well done.

It would appear no reward is given except from the in game benefits.